# vga Text mode can't print strings

Tags: ld, osdev, vga

I'm trying to make a small OS. So I wrote my bootloader that change to 32 protected mode and loads the kernel.
But when I try to print a string to the screen it only prints the first two characters and that's it. And when I try to print only single chars it works fine...
The [OSDev wiki says](https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen) that it is due to .rodata section missing in the linker script, but I do have on my script so I either didn't set it up correctly or I did something else wrong.

link.ld

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x1000;

    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.text.prologue)
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.bss)
    }

    end = .;
}
```

kernel.c

```
void main(){
    volatile char* video_memory = (volatile char*)0xb8000;
    const char* str = "hello, world!\0";

    while(*str != 0){
        *video_memory++ = *str++;
        *video_memory++ = 0x0a;
    }
}
```

As I said, when I run this it only prints "he" in light green and that's it.
The video mode is vga 80x25 text mode.

------------------------ EDIT --------------------------------
I tried this linker script that I found online and it worked!

```
ENTRY(_start) OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
phys = 0x001000;

SECTIONS
{
    . = phys;

    .entry              : { __entry_start = .;      *(.entry)   }
    .text               : { __text_start = .;       *(.text)    }
    .data               : { __data_start = .;       *(.data)    }
    .rodata             : { __rodata_start = .;     *(.rodata)  }
    .bss                : { __bss_start = .;        *(.bss)     }
    
    __end = .;
}
```

But I don't know why this one worked and the other one didn't, so can anyone explain it to me?